# How to insert an integer at specific index in a file using Jupyter-Notebook/python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[[image: The file on the left side is the data I have in the .txt file. The file on the right side displays what is the desired output.]]
The Image is the perfect display of my problem.

I have a .txt file. containing the alphabet: a b c d e f g h i ...

I want to insert a number with each letter, so the updated file look like this:

`a1 b2 c3 d4 e5 f6` and so on.

How can I do this in Python?

Note: Also, how to do the same when the letters are in a column, not a row?

Comment: If you include some code that shows what you've tried so far, you will be more likely to receive a better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is another solution based on your modified question.

you can write the output on the file

```
with open('s.txt') as s:
    alphabet = s.readlines()
    i = 1
    for l in alphabet:
        res = l.split()
        print(res[0], " ", (res[1] + str(i)))
        i = i+1
```

Output on the console

```
A   a1
B   b2
C   c3
D   d4
E   e5
F   f6
G   g7
H   h8
I   i9
J   j10
```

Comment: It's Perfect. It worked absolutely right. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('s.txt') as s:
    alphabet = s.read()
    lst = alphabet.split()
    for x in range( len(lst)):
        print(lst[x]+str(x+1)," ", end='')
```

output:

```
a1  b2  c3  d4  e5  f6
```

Comment: Yes. Thank You. It worked. Can this be tailored to specific column rather than the whole file. With this code, it gave numbers to every word. I want the numbers to be given only to the 2nd column.